# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_aspect'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

When I write the code:

```
for i in iaq:

fig, ax = plt.subplots(8,5,figsize=(8,5))
df_g2[df_g2['aq_date'] == i].plot(column='zone_id', cmap='Greens', ax=ax, legend=True)
ax.set_title('Analysis :'+ str(i))
plt.show()
```

it shows the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_aspect'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Don't try to use `.set_aspect` on a numpy array!  What kind of object has this method?  When you get a `no attribute` error, either you are trying to use the wrong method, or you have the wrong kind of object.  In Python, every class of object has a well defined set of methods.  You can't mix-and-match.

Comment: @hpaulj, even after removing set_aspect. It is showing the same error.

Comment: The variable `ax` is an 8x5 numpy array of Axes objects and the plot ha a grid of 40 subplots.  From the above, I guess you really meant `fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(8, 5))`.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I agree. But I want to visualize them side by side and it appears one by one and creates a huge line of images. What shoud I do?

Comment: If you want 40 subplots, then `subplots(8, 5)` is fine.  But then do `axs=subplots(8, 5); ax = axs[0, 3]` etc for each of the 40.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-two-directions